# sess_xxx in tmp folder but no sessions

Tags: php, session, tmp

I'm using PHP for my web service, it does not use any `session_xx` functions at all, but still I see new `sess_xxxxxx` files in `/tmp`, generated by the web service user.

Any idea on how find find why these are created, and how I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the cause, seems like some 3rd party lib was opening a session (facebook), and since I don't need it anymore, I commented out its usage and no more sessions :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have `session.auto_start` enable in your ini config file

Comment: I checked: session.auto_start = 0, so I don't think it's the cause